# Mock de método static com Demoiselle e PowerMock/Mockito

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, demoiselle, junit, mock

Estou tentando fazer um mock de um método static, porém o PowerMock obriga a utilização de um Runner (PowerMockRunner) específico para o mock static funcionar!

E para o Demoiselle funcionar é preciso iniciar o Weld com o DemoiselleRunner, mas a API do JUnit só aceita um único Runner.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) //DemoiselleRunner.class
@PrepareForTest(Fabrica.class)
public class MeuBCTest {

    @Inject
    private PrimeiroBC primeiroBC; //Não injeta com o PowerMockRunner
    private SegundoBC segundoBC;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        primeiroBC = Mockito.spy(primeiroBC);
        segundoBC = Mockito.mock(SegundoBC.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCamposObrigatoriosComSucesso() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Fabrica.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Fabrica.createSegundoBC()).thenReturn(segundoBC);

        primeiroBC.fazerAlgo(); //Internamente este método chama o Fabrica.createSegundoBC() para executar outra operação.

        //verificações

    }
}
```

Inicialmente pensei em criar meu próprio Runner estendendo do PowerMockRunner e adicionando o Weld como é feito no DemoiselleRunner.

Há alguma configuração no Demoiselle ou PowerMock para não precisar criar um outro Runner?

Answer (score 2):

Nunca usei o Demoiselle Framework. No entanto, a dificuldade com múltiplos *Runners* não é incomum e ocorre com outros frameworks.

Uma solução é usar o [PowerMockRule](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule). Segundo a documentação:

> Desde a versão 1.4 é possível iniciar o PowerMock usando uma regra do JUnit ([JUnit Rule](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules)) ao invés do `PowerMockRunner` e da anotação `RunWith`. (tradução livre)

Exemplo de uso:

```java
@RunWith(DemoiselleRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Fabrica.class)
public class MeuBCTest {

     @Rule
     PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

     ...

}
```

Comment: Funcionou em parte... ainda foi preciso adicionar a annotatio @PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*"}) na classe por conta de um bug (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/RUpBz4ufG-w).

Comment: @user3297199 Mas depois de adicionar essa anotação o teste foi executado com sucesso?

Comment: Ainda não por conta do PowerMock, aparentemente o ele roda os testes numa thread separada de onde o Demoiselle inicia o Weld. O CDI não está funcionando. Tem alguma dica?

Comment: Com relação à frequência de commits do Demoiselle, o projeto está no Github faz um bom tempo e não mais no SVN do SF.net. Você encontra os dados atualizados aqui: https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/network

Comment: @zyc Avaliei o framework no final de 2013 e na época não encontrei referências ao GitHub. Na verdade este não foi o único motivo para não tê-lo usado. Estou acessando o site oficial do framework agora e há várias informações desatualizadas. Gastei uns 20 minutos para descobrir algo sobre as últimas releases e nem consegui acessar o guia Quickstart na documentação. É mesmo preciso navegar nos diretórios do SourceForge para encontrar essas informações?

Answer (score 0):

Já tive um caso com `Arquilian`, e usei o `PowerMockRule` também, mas neste caso não foi usado o `Runner` do `Demoiselle`. No `Demoiselle` seguimos a orientação do `JUnit` que é estender `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`. Se não funcionar com o `PowerMockRule` talvez a solução seja, como você comentou, criar o seu próprio `Runner`. Quem sabe não pode criar um `DemoiselleRunnerPowerMock`? E caso não tenha sucesso sozinho em criar pode abrir um caso em: [frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br](http://tracker.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br)

OBS: O utluiz comentou que desistiu do `Demoiselle` por causa da frequências dos *commits*. Sua analise foi no repositório do [GitHub](https://github.com/demoiselle)? Pois não estamos mais usando o SVN do SourceForge depois da versão 2.